# generate shared access signature through python

Tags: python, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm tryng to generate a shared access signature link through python of my files which are already at blob storage, but something goes wrong , I received this message when I put the generate link on web browser:
"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

I'm generating the key from my container name on right button get shared access signature, but I can't go further.

````
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
#from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

datetime.utcnow()

from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, AccountSasPermissions,AccessPolicy


def generate_link():

    account_name='my_account_name_storage'
    container_name='container_name'
    blob_name='file_name.xsl'
    account_key='?sv=2019-12-12&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2020-09-17T05:49:57Z&st=2020-09-16T21:49:57Z&spr=https&sig=sdfsdhgbjgnbdkfnglfkdnhklfgnhklgf%30'
    url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=blob_name,
        permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )
    print(sas_token)
    url_with_sas = f"{url}?{sas_token}"
    print(url_with_sas)


generate_link()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong about `account_key` in your code.

To find `account_key` of your storage account, please nav to azure portal -> your storage account -> Settings -> Access keys, then you can see the `account_key`. The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: @user202135, if it solves your issue, please help accept it as answer, thanks:). And if you still have more issues, please let me know.